# What is the number of $1$s in $9+99+999+9999+\dotsb+\underbrace{999\ldots 999}_{\text{contains $2020$ $9$'s}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the sum $$9+99+999+\dotsb +\underbrace{999999\ldots 9999999}_{\text{contains $2020$ $9$'s}}$$ How many times does the digit $1$ appear?

I came across this in a maths competition paper. I got $2018$ as an answer, but I'm not sure whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Did you use a geometric series ? Then you probably made it right.

Comment: How is this series geometric?

Comment: $9 = 10^1 - 1$, $99 = 10^2 - 1$, $999 = 10^3 - 1$. Can you spot the pattern?

Comment: If you didn't use a geometric series, can you show us what you have tried? It's hard to verify your answer if we can't see your thought process.

Comment: Please cite the source of this problem.

Comment: $10+100+1000+\cdots$ and then subtract $2020$, this would have been my approach. But we need not a geometric series to note that we have a number containing of $2020$ ones and a zero from which $2020$ has to be subtracted.

Comment: Following Xander Henderson's comment, we get a lot of contest problems asked here. Because the year $2020$ appears in this problem, we need to make sure that you aren't asking a question from an ongoing competition.

Comment: But that would be far too tedious for the question is only asking for the number of times the digit 1 appears.

Comment: This question has been modified by me, so it is easier to word. The original question was different, but they both require the same concepts

Comment: @JiangMichael Please cite the source of this problem.  Questions on Math SE are expected to provide context and motivation, and a citation to a source helps to give that context.  Moreover, as you have stated that this is a contest problem (or based on one), a source really is required, as Math SE has a policy of closing problems from ongoing contests and soft-deleting any answers until after the contest has finished.  Please provide a source for this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sum is $$(10-1) + (100 - 1) + \cdots +(10^{2020}-1)$$

$$=111\cdots11110 - 2020$$

$$111\cdots109090.$$

There are $2020$ ones before you subtract the $2020.$  When you subtract, four of them go away.  So I think the answer is $2016.$

Comment: That is also my result.

Comment: What a beautiful answer; thank you for showing this method, it is really appreciated! :))

Answer (score 2):

The required number is $10+100+1000+....+10^{2020}-(1+1+1....)=111111...1110-2020$ where the total number of one's in the $11111...110$ is 2020. Since $111110-2020=109090$ we lost 4 one's. So in total we have 2016 one's.

In general if you sum up $10^{N}-1$ you get $N-4$ one's.

Comment: This is virtually a duplicate of B. Goddard's answer.

Comment: Did you mean that if you sum up $10^N-1$ **and then subtract $2020$** you get $N-4$ ones?